# How to perform View-Controller separation when using an "actioncolumn" (Ext.grid.column.Action)

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

In ExtJS 4, I have a grid that contains an action column. Whenever that action is triggered, I want to execute "my action".

Without MVC, this would look like this:

```
        /* ... */
        {
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            columns: [
                /* ... */
                {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    items: [{
                        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                            // my action
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Now I want to introduce the View-Controller separation. So I have to move the handler from the View to the Controller.

But how does the controller register its method to the action column? Looking at the [ExtJS 4.1 actioncolumn docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action), I can't find any event I could listen to. I also can't find a method to set the action column's handler afterwards.

So how can I achieve a clean View-Controller separation when using an actioncolumn?

Are actioncolumns not yet ready for MVC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not in actioncolumn but in its items which are not ExtJs Widgets. This items are simple images. That's why we cannot assign handlers in [control](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control) in such a way:

```js
this.control({
    'mygrid actioncolumn button[type=edit]' : this.onEdit
```

This way, however, would be the best one.

Unfortunately this way is impossible. But There is another way, which is almost as clean as the preferred one: make actioncolumn handler to fire grid's custom event (created by you):

```js
// view
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [{
        icon: 'http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/shared/icons/fam/cog_edit.png',
        tooltip: 'Edit',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            // fire custom event "itemeditbuttonclick"
            this.up('grid').fireEvent('itemeditbuttonclick', grid, rowIndex, colIndex);
        }},
```

```js
// controller
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > testpanel': {
            itemeditbuttonclick: this.onEdit,
            itemdeletebuttonclick: this.onDelete
        }
    });
},
```

### Example

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/g3prq/).

Answer (score 3):

This post explains an even simpler method than the accepted answer, if you only happen to have one type of `actioncolumn` item in your grid:

http://mitchellsimoens.com/actioncolumn-and-mvc/

Basically: just listen for the `actioncolumn`'s `click` event in your controller. However, this doesn't work if you need to distinguish between multiple `actioncolumn` types.

Comment: Now (11.12.2014) Mitch's post is here: http://mitchellsimoens.com/actioncolumn-and-mvc/