# Ext js how move date picker handler into controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, controller, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want move my DatePicker handler event into controller. But i do not know how catch handler event there.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGridPanel', {  
...........
    dockedItems:[
        {
            xtype:'toolbar',
            items:[
                {
                    id:'span3',
                    enableToggle:true,
                    text:'start date',
                    toggleGroup:'span',
                    scope:this,
                    menu:Ext.create('Ext.menu.DatePicker', {
                        handler:function (dp, date) {
                            grid=Ext.getCmp('MyGridPanelId');
                            var D = Ext.Date;
                            grid.startDate = date;

                            grid.setTimeSpan(D.add(date, D.HOUR, 8), D.add(grid.endDate, D.HOUR, 18));
                            debugger;
                        },
                        scope:this
                    })
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a controller and listen for the `select` event, simple example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyGridPanel', {
extends: 'Ext.app.Controller',
init: function() {
    this.control( 'toolbar > menu > datemenu', this.onDateSelect );
},
onDateSelect: function(dp, date) {
    grid=Ext.getCmp('MyGridPanelId');
    var D = Ext.Date;
    grid.startDate = date;
    grid.setTimeSpan(D.add(date, D.HOUR, 8), D.add(grid.endDate, D.HOUR, 18));
    debugger;
}

...........
```

Be aware that this will catch all your `DateMenu select` events, you probably want to use a more specialized selector on `this.control('...'`.

Comment: @user1827016 your comment doesn't help. Explain how its not working. Maybe consider editing your question to provide more details about what you have tried (source code) and what the results were.

Answer (score 0):

You can make menu handler to fire grid's custom event. And then catch it in your controller via `controll` method.

This technique is descreibed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721954/842075).

### Update

My preveous solution is a bit of overhead as there are selector combinations that you can use to catch menu's events without firing custom events. Try one of these selectors:

```
'gridpanel datemenu'
'#MyGridPanelId datemenu'
'gridpanel #span3'
'#span3'
```

for example:

```
// controller
// ...
init: function() {
    this.control({
       '#span3': {
           select: this.onDateSelect
       }
    });
},
onDateSelect: function(dp, date) {
    // ...
    debugger;
}
```

Comment: can you give me some example. How i can cath handler? I tried so much selectors...

Comment: @user1827016 updated answer. Give it a try now.